# Catching uninitialized/unreset variables in GDB

Tags: android, android-ndk, gdb, profiling, instrumentation

Android project with a native component. I'm using a third party library where I suspect there's an bug with uninitialized or unreset variable. The same sequence of calls (should be equivalent according to the interface definition) yields different results.

I've got the sources to the library, but I don't want to dig deep in them (it's really big and convoluted). Is there a way to leverage something like GDB to compare two runs of a piece of code - see if the variable state diverges at any point? It should not - the code is completely in-memory, no I/O or randomness there.

Comment: If you suspect uninitialized variables, you should use valgrind — that's what it's made for.